# How UDP protocol Number is 0x011?

Tags: ip, udp

How UDP protocol number is 0x11 when it's supposed to be 0x17 According to ianna website

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x11 is *hexadecimal* (base 16) for decimal 17.